# re.subbing multiple string patterns from a list of stopwords

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a list of stopwords with a space using `re.sub`, but getting hung up on how exactly to use a for loop to do it. My example code below is an attempt to insert `i` into the regexp pattern where `i` is each stopword within a for loop, but I get back the same text I put in.

```
text = codecs.open(path.join(d, 'replyAllText.txt'),'r', 'utf-8').read()
text = text.lower()



test = ['to', 'all', 'the']

for i in test:
text = re.sub('\b{}\b'.format(i) ," ", text)

print(text)
```

Comment: you need to escape the `\b` or use a raw string like `r'\b{}\b'`.

Comment: `re.sub` is inefficient algorithm for this case especially for large lists/texts. I would built prefix tree from file, and loop over text itself.

Answer (score 3):

Lacking the `r` prefix is what's causing your problem, as @tdelaney said. But you also have a better way to accomplish your task. Instead of repeatedly calling `re.sub` you can build a better regex using the alternation operation `|` and call `re.sub` only once:

```
test = ['to', 'all', 'the']
master_regex = '|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(w) for w in test)
text = re.sub(master_regex, ' ', text)
```